# Managing iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 image sizes

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to programming and Xcode and struggling with setting image size for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. Apparently both iPhone 5 and 6 use the @2x image while the 6+ use the @3x image. So i can design the 6+ perfectly, however since both iPhone 5 and 6 use the same image and they have different screen size/ resolution, mu screen design is impacted.

If I design the images as per iPhone 6 size, the images appear too big on iPhone 5 and if I design them as iPhone 5 then they appear to be too small on iPhone 6. This should be simple, what am I missing?

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of directly using the images you should create an entry for them in the Images.xcassets.  Select it in your Project Navigator.

[image]

Then drag and drop the @3x or @2x version of your image from the images folder into the list of images in the Images.xcassets window.  This will automatically generate a new entry.  Then drag the other (@2x or @3x) image into its proper position.  It will look like this in the end.

[image]

Once that is done you can use it in the UIImageView, or Image for a button or whatever in your Storyboard as just the name without the @2x or @3x.

**Now** to finally answer your question.  You should handle all of the image sizes with constraints in the storyboard.  So for instance if you want the same margins on either side of your image you will create constraints between the size of the `UIImageView` that contains your image and the edge of the Superview.  This way the image will be resized for each new screen.

[image]

**Edited to add**  Be careful of the `Constrain to margins` check box as you want to be consistent with using it or not otherwise you will get behavior you didn't plan for.  I always uncheck it and have my constraints go to the superview edge, but it doesn't matter as long as you are consistent across your App you won't get confused.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I am using the 2x and 3x versions of images in images.xcassets pretty much the same way you mentioned. I then set the constraints to position the image correctly. If I understand right, you are suggesting to also set margin constraints so the image may be resized for the bigger screen. I'll try this in morning to see if this resolves my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Exactly.  The nice thing about edge constraints and Autolayout is that when you are hit with a new size from Apple your code will conform (most of the time) and you won't have to do much to support the new size.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction:)